Why cant I import this file into my code in JavaScript?
I tried to import a file into a code but the foulder could not be found.
However when i try to type the name of the folder out it already suggests me the folder and recognizes it as such.
I also already have tried out to write the entire path out but the result is the same.
I hope someone can find my rookie mistake.
I have provided a screenshot where the folder name and the error can be found
Best Regards.enter image description here
enter image description here
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import "./globals.css";
import SigninForm from "./_auth/forms/SigninForm";
import { Home } from "./_root/pages";
import SignupForm from "./_auth/forms/SignupForm";
import AuthLayout from "./_auth/AuthLayout";
import RootLayout from "./_root";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <main className="flex h-screen">
      <Routes>
        {/* public routes */}
        <Route element={<AuthLayout />}>
          <Route path="sign-in" element={<SigninForm />} />
          <Route path="sign-up" element={<SignupForm />} />
        </Route>
        {/* private routes */}
        <Route element={<RootLayout />}>
          <Route index element={<Home />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </main>
  );
};

export default App;


./_root appears to be a folder.  Do you perhaps have a ./_root/RootLayout you were trying to import?  Your question should include where you expect that module to be located within your directory structure.  Or were you trying to use a _root/index.js file?

Please include all necessary information in the question as text, not just as a picture of text. Without looking at the pictures, we have no idea what import you're talking about. More here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

The path you give in the import statement must be the path to the JavaScript source file, not the directory where a source file is located.

I think "./ root" folder has a space, double check folder name again and remove it.

I checked and the cases are right and the path as well as u can see in the picture.. the previous imports have worked as well
